# EMR auto scaling behaviour with multiple scale-out rules on Task nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, autoscaling

I have two Scale-out rules:

Scale-out-rule-1: Add **1** instance if **YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage** is less than 15 for **1** five-minute period with a cooldown of 300 seconds.

Scale-out-rule-2: Add **5** instance if **ContainerPendingRatio** is greater than 0.75 for **1** five-minute period with a cooldown of 300 seconds.

Here if both scenarios are matching,

1. does it process both rules? Any order?
2. if the only one rule processed then which one and why?

Appreciate comments on similar scanario for scale in(cluster scale down).

Answer (score 7):

Q 1) does it process both rules? any order?

Only one rule will be processed when both rules  triggered at same time, EC2 Auto Scaling chooses the policy that provides the largest capacity.
In your case "Scale-out-rule-2" will be processed as it adds 5 instances and "Scale-out-rule-1" will be suspended.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#multiple-scaling-policy-resolution

Q 2) if the only one rule processed then which one and why?

Explained above

Comment: How do we know the rules and userguide for ec2 autoscaling apply to EMR?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to share my finding that I have learned

=== Two rules ====

- Scaling-out Rule1:
  Add 1 instance if YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage is < 15 for 1 five-minute period with a cooldown of 300 seconds.
- Scaling-out Rule2:
  Add 5 instance if ContainerPendingRatio is > .75 for 1 five-minute period with a cooldown of 300 seconds.

EMR cluster internally use "Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling" because EMR  Instance group is also a group with EC2 instance fleet.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html

Consequently,  its scaling out/in behavior follows that of "Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling". According to the doc[2],  when these situations occur, Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling ( attached the EMR instance group )  chooses the policy that provides the largest capacity for both scale out and scale in.  In this case, "ContainerPendingRatio" rule will be triggered because it adds 5 instances.  You can find more details/reason in the doc[2]

[2]  Multiple Scaling Policies
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#multiple-scaling-policy-resolution

I had experiments after creating EMR cluster in my account, and I see the same result as expected.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, any thoughts about *scale-in* with similar scenarios?

Comment: It's same. Basically it chooses to process the rule which benifits AWS.

Comment: What about if you are in a condition where both a scaling-out rule and a scaling-in rule could be applied at the same time? Suppose for example that after a cool down period you have the cluster that could scale-out for cores and scaling-in for memory? ( Could be the case where jobs use a lot of cores for executor but with few amount a memory ). Also in that case will be applied the largest capacity criteria? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I dont think it is possible there is no such thing available in amazon docs.